# Best Aproach to Relate A Entity Class to the Correspoding Table in a DataBase

Tags: c#, variables, entity, field, relate

i want to relate each Field of  an Entity Class to the corresponding datatable Field. 
im working on c# currently

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Thank you guys. looks like ill stop my current DB Entity Binding project for now and take a crack at these entity frameworks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Entity Framework does exactly that, and very well.  It also does a whole lot more such as let you write strong typed LINQ queries directly from your application code.

your other good options are NHibernate or Linq to SQL

this class of frameworks is generally called Object Relational Mapper (ORM)

I would say Entity Framework offers the most conveniences for beginners such as visually configuring your data model.  it can infer your object model from your database or it can create a database for you from your object model.

The new Entity Framework Code First approach is incredibly simple and powerful in my opinion
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/ef-feature-ctp4-walkthrough-code-first)

Answer (score 1):

It is what [entity framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) is doing, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's ADO.NET team just published an Entity Framework Beginners Guide at their team blog:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/absolute-beginners-guide-to-entity-framework)